# Is Stack Exchange affected by the upcoming mass revocation of Let's Encrypt SSL certificates?

Tags: support, ssl

For a few years now, Stack Exchange has used Let's Encrypt as their SSL security certificate provider.

Just today, a large number of security certificates issued by Let's Encrypt [were found to have been incorrectly issued](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/lets-encrypt-is-revoking-lots-of-ssl-certificates-in-two-days/) and will be revoked in two days. This affects certificates issued in the last 90 days, and the most recent certificate was issued three weeks ago.

Is Stack Exchange affected by this certificate mis-issue? If so, can it please be fixed before the mass revocation?

Comment: If it had been timed right, a certificate warning could have been combined with a "User Interface warning" :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites should not be impacted by the Let's Encrypt cert revocations. Only certs using the [TLS-ALPN-01](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#tls-alpn-01) challenge are at issue, and we don't use that challenge type. In addition, Let's Encrypt has [notified subscribers](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/questions-about-renewing-before-tls-alpn-01-revocations/170449) with impacted certs (and valid contact emails) and we haven't received that email. They've also [published a csv of affected certs](https://tls-alpn-01-data.letsencrypt.org/tls-alpn-01-affected-certs-by-regID.csv.gz). I've done a cursory search for some of our domains and haven't found any.

Comment: Thank you! With that file I was able to test a bunch of my key domains, just in case somehow I didn't get the email.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, new contributor :)